# How to use row by row value for calculation from .mat file

Tags: matlab

```html
function [inilife,ini_cycle] = cycode(a,b,c)

ld =load('allstresscomp.mat');% loading .mat file of(81290 rows and 6 colomns)
% from this .mat file I want extract row by row values(6 values of column)

ini_cycle=zeros(length(ld),1);

for Z=1:1:length(ld(:,1))
        sigc11=ld(Z,1);
        sigc12=ld(Z,6);
        sigc13=ld(Z,5);
        sigc22=ld(Z,2);
        sigc23=ld(Z,4);
        sigc33=ld(Z,3);
            
    sigc = [sigc11; sigc12; sigc13; sigc22; sigc23; sigc33];   
        
    matstress = a*sigc;
    
    sigm1 = matstress(1,1);
    sigm2 = matstress(2,1);
    sigm3 = matstress(3,1);
    sigm23 = matstress(4,1);
    sigm31 = matstress(5,1);
    sigm12 = matstress(6,1);
   
    It = [sigm2 + sigm3 + sqrt((sigm2 +sigm13)^(2)- 4*(sigm12*sigm23 + sigm1^(2)))]/2;
    
    N(Z) = It + c - b; % this is one answer for values of one row of .mat file
    ini_cycle(Z,1)=N(Z); 
end 
inilife = N;
```

I am a beginner for Matlab trying for one small code. I'm having `.mat` file `(allstresscomp.mat)` of size `[81920(rows),6(columns)]`. How can I use all 6 values of first row of .mat file in a code & then find a answer. Again use all 6 values of second row of `.mat` file in a code then find a answer and so on till last 81290 rows & saving these row by row answers in some `variable 'N'`. And last I can get my answers for any row I call for from `'N'` ? I have attached my `'cycles_code.m'`.

```
function [inilife,ini_cycle] = cycles_code(cc, cf, cm,sif,sim,bt,bs1,bs2,freq,actvol,planck,U,k,T,loadratio)
    d = cc-cf;
    e = cc-cm;
    f = inv(d);
    A = -(sim/sif)*(f\e);
    I = eye(6);
    g = (sim*I)+(sif*A);
    h = inv(g);
    ld =load('allstresscomp.mat');
    ini_cycle=zeros(length(ld),1);
     for Z=1:1:length(ld(:,1))
            sigc11=ld(Z,1);
            sigc12=ld(Z,6);
            sigc13=ld(Z,5);
            sigc22=ld(Z,2);
            sigc23=ld(Z,4);
            sigc33=ld(Z,3);
            N = 0;
        sigc = [sigc11; sigc12; sigc13; sigc22; sigc23; sigc33];   
        j = h\inv(cc)*sigc;      
        matstress = cm*j;
        sigm1 = matstress(1,1);
        sigm2 = matstress(2,1);
        sigm3 = matstress(3,1);
        sigm23 = matstress(4,1);
        sigm31 = matstress(5,1);
        sigm12 = matstress(6,1);
        It = [sigm2 + sigm3 + sqrt((sigm2 +sigm3)^(2)- 4*(sigm2*sigm3 + sigm23^(2)))]/2;
        Is1 = sigm12^(2) + sigm31^(2);
        Is2 = 0.25*(sigm2-sigm3)^(2) + sigm23^(2);
        At = bt/bs1;
        As = bs2/bs1;
        effstress = sqrt(At*It^(2) + Is1 + As*Is2);
        sigmax = effstress;
        sigmin = loadratio*sigmax;
        actvoll = actvol/(6.02214179*10^(23));
        V = U/(6.02214179*10^(23));
        a = (actvoll*sigmax)/(k*T);
        b = (actvoll*sigmin)/(k*T);
        p = a*log10(exp(1));
        q = log10(1-2^((b*log10(exp(1)))-(a*log10(exp(1)))));
        c = p+q;
        d = (V/(k*T))*log10(exp(1));
        e = log10((freq*actvoll*planck*(sigmax-sigmin))/(k*T)^2);
        N(Z) = e+d-c;
        ini_cycle(Z,1)=N(Z);
    end 
    inilife = N;
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum reproducible example

Comment: Please find for smaller version of code 'cycode.m'above,

Answer (score 1):

If you read your .mat value and the input matrix is called `inputMatrix` then you can 1) loop over rows

```
outputValue = []
for rowIndex = 1:size( inputMatrix, 1)
   data = inputMatrix( rowIndex, :)

   outputValue( rowIndex) = result of calculation on data
end
```

2) better, vectorize the thing. 
I won't write a solution to your problem because that highly depends on what you're calculating. for example, if your output is a sum of values in a row, there's a one-liner

```
outputValue = sum( inputMatrix, 2) % along the second dimension - horizontal
```

or

```
outputValue = inputMatrix( :, 1) .* inputMatrix( :, 2) + inputMatrix( :, 3) .^ 2
```

the . notation is not necessary (element-by-element) in this example,but adds up to readability.

any basic tutorial for Matlab explains vectorized operations in the language

Comment: When I Ioad .mat file then from that file I want to extract first row values (there are six coloumns hence six values) then use these values in my formula which will produce one answer. Then execute it for second row values of .mat file then it will give second answer and so on........And finally I want call the answers whichever I need.

Comment: please find smaller version of code 'cycode.m' above.

Comment: Can you please little more explicite on your first suggetion?

Comment: in the first suggestion the variable `data` holds all the values of the "current" row in the original order and nothing else (no other part of the `inputMatrix`). So in that place it is easy to pass that variable to, for instance, a function which only calculates whatever you need on that single row's data without the need of handling a the rest of the input.

Comment: the `outputValue` is effectively the vector holding a result for each row of the `inputMatrix`. In my code it is dynamic, that is, it extends as you add result values to it (not the best way, though, become slow for large sizes). You may initiate it with `outputValue = zeros( size( inputMatrix,1), 1);` instead of using `[]`.

Comment: Yes I did it by implementing the same. I feel vectorizing it is quite complex for it since I have to do many calculation on the extracted row data of inputmatrix.